# Django-Angularjs dynamic rating app

Tags: django, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I trying to create a Angularjs rating app with django. I'm using the rating mechanism from angular-bootstrap. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I've created a controller which can handle ratings for only one object but i would like to create an app witch can rate any object on my website no matter where they are.
To identify each object, I using:

> data-id="{{ id }}" data-app-label="{{ app_label }}" data-model="{{ model }}"

My template:

```
<div ng-app="ratingApp">
    <div ng-controller="RatingCtrl">
        <div class="rating-input">
            <div rating id="rating" ng-model="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" on-leave="overStar = null" data-id="{{ id }}" data-app-label="{{ app_label }}" data-model="{{ model }}" ng-click="postRating(value)"></div>
            <div class="menge thanks" ng-hide="showMessage"><span>{$ menge $}</span></div>
            <div class="message"><div class="ng-hide thanks" ng-show="showMessage">{$ message $}</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
ratingControllers.controller('RatingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$element', '$timeout',

    function ($scope, $http, $element, $timeout) {

        var messageTimer = false,
            displayDuration = 2000;

        $scope.message = "Thanks!";
        $scope.showMessage = false;

        $scope.doGreeting = function () {
            if (messageTimer) {
                $timeout.cancel(messageTimer);
            }

            $scope.showMessage = true;

            messageTimer = $timeout(function () {
                $scope.showMessage = false;
            }, displayDuration);
        };

        $scope.max = 6;
        $scope.isReadonly = false;

        var id = $element.find("#rating").attr("data-id");
        var app_label = $element.find("#rating").attr("data-app-label");
        var model = $element.find("#rating").attr("data-model");

        var request = $http.post("/rating/get-rating/", {id: id, app_label: app_label, model: model});
        request.success(function (data) {
            $scope.rate = data.sterne;
            $scope.menge = data.menge;
        });

        $scope.postRating = function (value) {
            var request = $http.post("/rating/set-rating/", {id: id, app_label: app_label, model: model, sterne: $scope.rate});
            request.success(function (data) {
                $scope.doGreeting();
                if (data.message) {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            });
        };

    }
]);
```

Any idea how can i make this more reusable to rate any object on the website?

Comment: You can a create a custom directive which will do the works you have done inside this controller. And you will be able to use it anywhere in your html.

Comment: What about the bootstrap directive "rating"? Are there any conflicts when I write a new directive for the same object? Can you make an example to point me in the right direction?